# Why double contact structure reduces resistance?

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, analog, resistance, circuit-design

I am watching the video lecture [here](https://youtu.be/gFj7BMPAWJk?t=3478) (at 58:11) and the professor explain why the double contact reduces the resistance by a factor of four. I watched it several times and din't get it. Could anyone explain more? To me the resistance of that wire section is R no matter it is driven by one or two sources.

[image]

Link: video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFj7BMPAWJk&feature=youtu.be&t=3478) and lecture note [here](http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/icdesign/ee240_sp10/lectures/Lecture02_Passives_2up.pdf) (page 34)

Comment: Are you aware that this is the **series resistance** Rs of an **on-chip capacitor** we're dealing with here ? Your question is confusing as it does not mention **capacitor** anywhere. Contacting a plate of a capacitor on **both sides** as opposed to **only one side** does decrease Rs by a factor 4.

Comment: Oh, yes, but as you see the example that professor drew with contact resistance, why R/2 here and why they are in parallel so R/2 in parallel with R/2 (the result is R/4)?

Comment: You focus on **contact resistance** but that is not what this is about, it is about the series resistance of the whole capacitor. Note that the capacitor plates have a non-zero sheet resistance. That is reduced by adding the opposite contact. The resistance from contact to plate can be assumed zero, it is not what is discussed here.

Comment: I suggest to watch the video again and listen to what he says

Comment: @PlasmaHH: can you explain why it drops by a factor of 4?

Comment: @anhnha: I can not add any more to the rather clear explanation he does with is hand drawing of the half resistance resistors. You might as a first instance ty to understand why they are halved.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: why it is R/2? Why find the resistance by looking at the middle?

Comment: @anhnha: because now you reach the "plate" from two sides.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: what do you mean by opposite contact here?

Comment: opposite contact = the extra (2nd) contact added on the other (opposite) side.

Comment: I still don't get it. The series resistance of that sheet is R, why does it depend on the contact and number of driving source? For example, for the normal resistor, its resistance is always R no matter it is driven by one or two sources.

Comment: You have asked many, many questions and you have hardly accepted any answers at all. Looking through a few I can see that many questions have reasonable answers that deserve to be formally accepted. May I suggest that you "pay the fee for good information" and then you might get answers that are more helpful. It's a small price to pay for getting great information.

Comment: @Andyaka: OK but why is the point important too much? The only reason I like that point is that because I can use it for bounty. So I thought that every one would be the same. I somtimes accept some answers but normally I don't care that much. If it is such that important then I will.

Comment: @anhnha you don't have to accept any answers if you don't want to. It's a free world and my opinion is just that, my opinion. You just have to ask yourself if not accepting a lot of good answers limits the responses you might get in the future.

Comment: @Andyaka: OK, it is not that I don't want or don't appreciate answers that I get. I upvote almost all answers I get. However, I normally wait for some more answer and then forget to accept if I am not received any new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the plate as a sheet with uniform resistivity.

Now consider that with a contact at each side, no current will flow across the centre line of the sheet. Why not? Because it will flow to the nearest terminal. So you could cut the double contact sheet down the centre line without affecting its operation, and arrange the two halves side by side.

Obviously you have halved the length of the sheet, halving its resistance.

But you now have two of them, connected in parallel....

Comment: Thanks. But why there is no current will flow across the centre line ?

Comment: Draw a grid of resistors, and start sketching charge flows and electric potentials. Add some metal stripes. You get to train your brain to view the world as Finite Element Model, a grid of resistors and capacitors suitable for SPICE. Now try the SPICE view of a capacitor.....................on silicon. Train your brain.

Comment: Because it will flow to the nearest terminal.